# Google Maps consuming battery

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, google-maps, micromax-yu-yureka

I've recently updated Google Maps to **version 9.16.2** and it is draining battery like anything.

I tried disabling it but it starts again and again and consumes battery

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: I can report the same issue on LG E989, after this google maps update, battery can't last 8 hours, normally it go for 70 hours or more. i'll try to force stop and test along the day.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it will not consume battery after disable. I don't know much about the  Map version 9.16.2.

Can you try with force stop the Map app.
Please check the link below how an app is disabling

http://www.howtogeek.com/195786/how-to-closestop-a-running-app-on-an-android-device/

Comment: Please seek clarification using comments on the question. You would need 50 reputation points to comment anywhere.

Comment: Actually i have tried to get clarification by commenting, but it needs 50 reputation. So my only option was to put the answer with my own knowledge.

Comment: Shalu, "disabling" an app just makes it "invisible" and keeps it from receiving broadcasts. If some other app calls an intent of it, it is still started. Especially GMaps is known for this (had it quite often on devices with GApps). *Greenify* might help then, but I'm not entirely sure.